# How to catch DNS request using 'netstat' in Unix

Tags: domain-name-system, netstat, aix

I am working in a bank where 'netcat' is not there. I am having problem wherein one DNS server of the two going down is causing impact. In order to troubleshoot, I need to catch the request (incoming and outgoing) from the DNS clients (AIX). How can I do it? Netstat does not do with the options, I used

Comment: You can also strace/truss the clients. But typically you have to use tcpdump like tools. Netstat is not used for request contents and may not even show udp sockets as they are too short lived.

Comment: netstat only shows whether a port is open.  You need to use a tool such as tcpdump to inspect traffic. If you're in a high secure environment, you may need to find out how to get permission to use it.

Comment: Perhaps you can turn on good enough logging at the DNS server?

Comment: If you have two DNS servers configured and one goes down, it's quite normal that it will have an impact on clients configured to use both (at the very least random slow downs as the DNS clients waits for a timeout before moving on to the other server). If you want high availability, you need to make sure the IPs the client use are moved to another active server whenever one goes down.

Comment: Other tools that may be useful in diagnosing things are of course `nslookup` and `dig`.

Comment: Make sure you know if you're looking for TCP or UDP requests... Most DNS runs on UDP.

Comment: Jcaron, You wrote "If you have two DNS servers configured and one goes down, it's quite normal that it will have an impact on clients configured to use both".  I do not understand why. Please note that both the DNS servers have same data. Also note that there is no reported impact from Solaris or Windows desktops

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Netstat almost certainly won't be able to help you**.

Netstat displays open sockets and active connections *at the moment you execute the program*. A DNS request will happen entirely too quickly for you to catch it because it'll be gone and done in less time than it takes to type out the command parameters. Moreover, UDP is stateless, so there *isn't an active connection to see to begin with*.

What you want instead is `tcpdump`. This program allows you to record network traffic depending on the parameters you give it.

`tcpdump -w dnsrequests.pcap -i any udp and port 53` will capture all UDP traffic on port 53 on all interfaces and save it to the file `dnsrequests.pcap`. You can then open that file in [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and study it at your leisure.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, `netstat` also shows recently completed TCP connections (in `TIME_WAIT` state, usually), and DNS can in some cases use TCP. It is most likely using UDP and would indeed not be visible using `netstat`, though.

Answer (score 19):

I don't think `netstat` will let you inspect the actual traffic but `tcpdump` will if you don't have access to `netcat`. `tcpdump udp port 53` should show you the traffic.

Comment: Yes, except that DNS uses **both** UDP and TCP...

Comment: DNS *can* use TCP, but in practice it rarely does since it's a nontrivial amount of overhead compared to straight UDP.

Answer (score 3):

I saw tcpdump mentioned elsewhere here and while it is very suitable for the task some people might prefer to use a graphical application such as Wireshark!

Comment: wireshark is not available in secured environments like bank. I am surprised the 'netstat' does not catch even with -u option

Comment: @BimanRoy: netstat never was a packet capture tool (on AIX or any other Unix I've come across).

Comment: @bimanroy netstat doesn't do packet capture. Also, if `tcpdump` is available, you can output the dump to a file and read the file with wireshark on another system.

Comment: @BimanRoy: well if wireshark ought to be blocked then tcpdump ought to be blocked as well right?